# What data storage method to use for a survey app on iOS

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm trying to create a survey app for iOS that will store data on the device. The app also needs to be able to run statistics on the survey data.

Example questions might be:

What day is it?
Pick a number 1 - 10.
What is your favorite color?
Did you eat breakfast?

Each survey needs to be stored (preferably on the device) as its own item/event/table row.

| Monday | 9 | blue | yes |

Then I want the app to run and display statistics on the data.

What are the totals/averages for surveys taken on Monday? Tuesday? Etc?
What percentage chose blue?
What percentage have blue and yes?

This seems like a relatively simple app, but I'm a beginner. My biggest question now is: What method of data storage should I use? Archiving? Core data? Something else?

Comment: What are you familiar with? There's probably no right answer. SQLite is what I would use.

Comment: Core Data is incredibly easy to set up and manage.  It also requires no knowledge of SQL code and can be used to store your data easily.

Comment: See, two responses have yielded two different answers, and neither is wrong. For that reason, I've flagged this as "not constructive".

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'm not familiar at all with SQL and only have a basic understanding of databases. I am also very new to programming in general and iOS programming in particular. I have recently read a few books: Objective-C 2.0 Essentials and iPhone iOS 6 Development Essentials both by Neil Smyth, and a Big Nerd Ranch book on Objective-C programming.

Because my program SEEMS relatively simple I was looking for just that basic "which would be a good, simple tool to use" type info. I think SQLite is likely the best solution so I'll dig into that more. Thanks.